# Inserting matrix/array in Table of Contents

Tags: table-of-contents, matrices

I am trying to insert an equation containing matrix inside ToC.

```
\subsection{Cross Product }
\subsubsection{Cartesian : $\nabla \times A = 
\left|
\begin{array}{ccc} 
a_x & a_y & a_z\\ 
\dfrac{\partial}{\partial x} & \dfrac{\partial}{\partial y} & \dfrac{\partial}{\partial z}\\ 
A_x & A_y & A_z 
\end{array} 
\right| $}
```

This gives an Error:

```
! Paragraph ended before \@dottedtocline was complete.
```

Answer (score 4):

I'd suggest you not to place the math expression into the ToC I would even suggest you not to use the expression in the title of the subsubsection; it looks really ugly and I think there's really no need for this.

In any case, if you *really* need the matrix in the title, you could use the optional argument for `\subsubsection` to provide a more convenient entry for the ToC (as in my first example below); if you *really* need the expression in the ToC (but, again, I'd advise you not to), the you'll need to `\protect` some commands (as in the second example):

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{amsmath}

\setcounter{tocdepth}{5}
\begin{document}

\tableofcontents

\section{Test section}
\subsection{Cross Product } 
\subsubsection[Cartesian cross product]{Cartesian : $\nabla \times A = \left| \begin{array}{ccc} a_x & a_y & a_z\\ \dfrac{\partial}{\partial x} & \dfrac{\partial}{\partial y} & \dfrac{\partial}{\partial z}\\ A_x & A_y & A_z \end{array} \right| $}
\subsubsection{Cartesian : $\nabla \times A = \left| \protect\begin{array}{ccc} a_x & a_y & a_z\\ \dfrac{\partial}{\partial x} & \dfrac{\partial}{\partial y} & \dfrac{\partial}{\partial z}\\ A_x & A_y & A_z \protect\end{array} \right| $}

\end{document}
```

[image]

By the way, since you already load `amsmath`, instead of an `array` and the `\left`, `\right` pair, you could use `vmatrix` from `amsmath`, as in

```
\begin{vmatrix} 
a_x & a_y & a_z \\ 
\dfrac{\partial}{\partial x} & \dfrac{\partial}{\partial y} & \dfrac{\partial}{\partial z} \\ 
A_x & A_y & A_z 
\end{vmatrix}
```

Of course, if you insist in placing this in the ToC, you'll need to use `\protect` as before.